# Using records as table name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has table names in them. I would like to run a query to return them and then use them as a table name for another query.

```
select tablenames 
from tablelist
```

Results:

```
tablenames
----------
table1
table2
table3
```

I then want to use those table names in a query together:

```
DECLARE @table_name varchar(max)

SET @table_name = (SELECT tablenames from tablelist)

EXEC('SELECT * FROM  ' + @table_name)
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

What I would like it to do is something similar:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
SELECT * FROM table2
SELECT * FROM table3
```

Comment: Search on dynamic sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''
Select @SQL = @SQL+'Select * From '+quotename(tablenames)+';'+char(13)
  From tablelist
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```

**The Generated SQL Looks Like this**

```
Select * From [table1];
Select * From [table2];
Select * From [table3];
```

Comment: I was able to use this to get exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Lynx Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Everybody using SQL Server has a table with table names in it - sys.tables:

```
SELECT 
    t.name
FROM
    sys.tables t
JOIN
    sys.schemas s
ON
    s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE
    t.name NOT IN ('sysdiagrams')
```

The SQL below will create an output that has every table you find the above query, along with a table count.  If you have only specific tables you want to use, edit the query that updates @Columns to grab the table names you want:

```
DECLARE
@Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
@SQL_Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  
    @Columns = ISNULL( @Columns + ', ', '') +  'SELECT TblName = ''' +t.name+''', NbrOfRows = COUNT(*) FROM ' + t.name 
FROM
    sys.tables t
JOIN
    sys.schemas s
ON
    s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE
    t.name NOT IN ('sysdiagrams')

SELECT
    @Columns = REPLACE(@Columns, ', SELECT', ' UNION SELECT')

SELECT @SQL_Statement = '' + @Columns + ''

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @SQL_Statement = @SQL_Statement
```

You could change this to use your table of table names:

```
DECLARE
@Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
@SQL_Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  
    @Columns = ISNULL( @Columns + ', ', '') +  'SELECT TblName = ''' +t.tablesname+''', NbrOfRows = COUNT(*) FROM ' + t.tablenames 
FROM
    tablelist

SELECT
    @Columns = REPLACE(@Columns, ', SELECT', ' UNION SELECT')

SELECT @SQL_Statement = '' + @Columns + ''

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @SQL_Statement = @SQL_Statement
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a cursor, you can achieve what you are looking to do with the following SQL.

```
DECLARE @tableList CURSOR;
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(500);
BEGIN
    SET @tableList = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT      tableName 
    FROM        dbo.tableList

    OPEN        @tableList
    FETCH NEXT 
    FROM        @tableList
    INTO        @tableName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET         @cmd = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName
        PRINT       @cmd
        EXEC        sp_executeSQL @cmd
        FETCH NEXT 
        FROM        @tableList
        INTO        @tableName
    END; 
CLOSE       @tableList ;
DEALLOCATE  @tableList;
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use either a cursor or a loop. Something like this might work for you.

```
DECLARE @table_name varchar(max)
SELECT @table_name = MIN(tablenames) FROM tablelist;
WHILE @table_name IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC('SELECT * FROM  ' + @table_name)
    SELECT @table_name = MIN(tablenames) FROM tablelist WHERE tablenames > @table_name;
END;
```